# Mongo based session persistence using SparkJava (jetty 9.4.x)

Tags: session, persistence, embedded-jetty, spark-java

We are Implementing Mongo based session persistence using SparkJava (version 2.6.0 with Jetty 9.4.x). we required to store jetty session into mongoDB. How i can achieve it in SparkJava? I found many example of using MongoSessionIdManager and MongoSessionManager with jetty-nosql (9.3.x). but MongoSessionIdManager and MongoSessionManager no longer exist in jetty-nosql (9.4.x).

I think this topic was discussed at https://github.com/perwendel/spark/pull/836 but not able to find example of implementation..

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I Got it working after customizing SparkJava library and generated spark-core-2.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

added working Example of MongoDB and JDBC based session clustering using SpakrJava at My [GitHub repository](https://github.com/bhuva3/spark-session-persistence)